# @ManyToMany Join Table fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have run into a problem that I haven't been able to solve yet.

Environment:

- MySQL 5
- OS X
- Hibernate 4.1
- Spring 3.1
- Spring Data JPA

I have two entities in a ManyToMany relationship.  I use a Join table with foreign keys for this.
Here are my entities (modified for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class Employee  {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Long employeeId;

@ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Office.class )
@JoinTable( name = "EmployeeOfficeJoin", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "EmployeeId", nullable = false, updatable = false ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "OfficeId", nullable = false, updatable = false ) } )
private List<Office> offices = new ArrayList<Office>();
}
```

AND

```
@Entity
public class Office {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
private Long officeId;

@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "offices", targetEntity = Employee.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

My join table is:

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dental`.`EmployeeOfficeJoin` ( 
   `EmployeeId` BIGINT(11) ,
   `OfficeId` BIGINT(11),
   PRIMARY KEY ( `employeeId`, `officeId` ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( `employeeId` ) REFERENCES `Employee` (`EmployeeId` ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( `officeId` ) REFERENCES `Office` ( `Officeid` ) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I am using this naming:

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

when I try to use this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
...
emp.getOffices().add(newOffice);
employeeRepository.save(emp);
```

the last insert statement before failure is:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        EmployeeOfficeJoin
        (EmployeeId, OfficeId) 
    values
        (?, ?)
TRACE - BasicBinder                - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
TRACE - BasicBinder                - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1
DEBUG - SqlExceptionHelper         - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dental`.`employeeofficejoin`, CONSTRAINT `employeeofficejoin_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeId`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`EmployeeId`)) [n/a]
```

It appears that the case is all changed, and I see that [someone](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/hibernate-mysql-mac-foreign-key-nightmares-a-painless-solution-to-a-painful-problem/) thinks this might be a MySQL on OS X issue.  but when I use

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

that doesn't fix it for me.

So does anyone know if this is a naming strategy issue or something else?

Comment: Did you try enabling updates instead of disabling them?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "enabling updates".  I don't think I have disabled anything intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect a different error though, but the fields defined in the JoinColumn do not seem to match what you've specified as fields in the relation table.  Try fixing the join columns in the annotation to refer to "Employee_id" and "Office_id" instead of "EmployeeId" and "OfficeId".

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post to show the correct create EmployeeOfficeJoin sql.

Comment: I tried changing all table name to be lowercase.  However, the column names are also camel case, and I now get error like:  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: address_id in dental.address   Where address.AddressId definitely exists

Comment: Turn on logging to see what it is trying to do with the failing statement and the transaction, and check what is in the database.

Comment: When I step thru the code, all seems to work fine.  As the @Transaction method ends, the logging output shows commit and then the exception is thrown from mysql.  Data is not actually saved to the table because the transaction rolls back.

Comment: You need to look at and post the insert statements and verify they are correct.  There could be an issue with sequencing or something else that you might not have posted.

Comment: I updated my post with the last insert statement before the exception is thrown.  I am able to manually run each insert statement, but the one for the join table fails.

Comment: Right, but did one of the previous statements insert to the employee table with an ID value of 1?

Comment: OK, the solution is.....upgrading MySQL to version 5.5.28 from 5.5.11 on my OS X laptop.  Once I did that, everything was fine.  Strangely, my Linux instance MySQL is 5.1.66 did not have these issues.  My suspicion is this is related to case sensitivity differences.  Thank you everyone for your thoughts in helping me trouble shoot it.